# Acts as taggable on - enum methods not working in tags table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, ruby-on-rails-5, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/) gem. It creates `tags` and `taggings` tables automatically. But I wanted to add an additional column called `status` to `tags` table. I generated a migration to add `status` column.

I then created a file named `tag.rb` under `app/models`

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: { public: 0, private: 1 }
end
```

`Tag.first.private?` works

but

`ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.first.private?` is not working

Throws this error:
`NoMethodError (undefined method 'is_private?' for #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag:0x00007fb8414b4028>)`

I even did

```
module ActsAsTaggableOn
  class Tag < ApplicationRecord
    enum status: { public: 0, private: 1 }
  end
end
```

Somehow, this too doesn't work. Can someone point out what's wrong.

Edit:
This is the migration file

```
class AddStatusToTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :tags, :status, :integer, default: 0, null: false
  end
end
```

Comment: What does your migration (where you added `status` to `tags`) look like? I am speculating that you added the column to the wrong table.

Comment: can you try `::ActiveRecord::Base` instead of `ApplicationRecord `?

Comment: @jvillian I edited the question to add the migration file.

Comment: @emaillenin, thank you it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `::ActiveRecord::Base` instead of `ApplicationRecord`

```
module ActsAsTaggableOn
  class Tag < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    enum status: { public: 0, private: 1 }
  end
end
```